# Load function in opencv doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I've tried to take code for face recognition with webcamera based on OpenCV library. The problem is, code works until cascades try to load.

```
(if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };).
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Opencv v4.5.4. In project properties I've pointed the way to include and libraries directories.

I've tried to point to absolute path `C:/Users/.../opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml`, and relative path.

Piece of code:

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include "Tserial.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);

/** Global variables */
//-- Note, either copy these two files from opencv/data/haarscascades to your current folder, or change these locations
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
    
    if (!eyes_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
```

Terminal application closes after face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name).

Tell me please, what could be the problem. Maybe the path I've pointed doesn't look right?

Comment: is the file actually there? windows paths require backslashes, not forward slashes. compatibility exists sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Yes, the file actually there. Forward slashes is for visual studio syntax.

Comment: you use relative paths. relative paths aren't resolved relative to the *position* of the program, but relative to the *current working directory*, which can be different. -- do you have any funny characters in the path?

Comment: I’ve tried to use absolute path (c:/Users/.../opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml).

Comment: test with normal C++ (no OpenCV involved) if you can open and read that XML file.